# Mecanismo de pesquisa personalizada google

Tags: google

Possuo um mecanismo de pesquisa personalizada do google do site https://cse.google.com/cse, fiz todas as configurações porem quando efetuo alguma pesquisa só me retorna: **Sem resultados.** Mesmo tendo resultados. Alguem que mexa com isso sabe como funciona?

Obrigado.